# append each link only once per class

Tags: jquery, class, hyperlink, append, each

Let's say I have 4 x img tags with the same class and each has different url. I can retrieve each url with this code:

```
$('.userPicture img').each(function(){
    var getImageLink = $(this).attr('src');
    console.log(getImageLink)
});
```

Console.log:

```
http://link1.com
http://link2.com
http://link3.com
http://link4.com
```

The quesion is how to append each link only once per class?

```
$.each(getImageLink, function(i) {
    $('.aboutInfo').eq(i).append('<p><a href="'+getImageLink+'"></a></p>');
```

});

Best result I can get is:

```
.aboutInfo
http://link1.com
http://link2.com
http://link3.com
http://link4.com

.aboutInfo
http://link1.com
http://link2.com
http://link3.com
http://link4.com
```

what I need is:

```
.aboutInfo
http://link1.com

.aboutInfo
http://link2.com
```

etc...

I can't figure it out by myselft :(

Comment: Appending a link that has no text in between the `<a>` and the `</a>` won't do anything useful (it will just be a zero length link).  Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?  What text do you want to be clickable in the link?

Comment: The link could have a background image associated with it...

Comment: @brandwaffle - I see no signs that that's what the OP is trying to do and there's nothing that would give the link any size to even have any size to show a background image.  I think the OP just left something out of what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
$('.userPicture img').each(function(i, el){
  var getImageLink = $(el).attr('src');
  $('.aboutInfo').eq(i).append('<p><a href="'+getImageLink+'"></a></p>');
});
```

The key is to do the appending inside the .each loop...that way getImageLink will be the proper value (it's in scope) and it will append to each link once.

UPDATE: To answer the question posed in the comments, you don't need to have text in a link to have it work. The CSS could simply be this:

```
.aboutInfo {
  background: url(http://server.com/images/20x100-image.png) center left no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

Either way, the question of why the link has no text is not really the point of the OP's question, but hopefully this explanation will help anyone who's curious.

Comment: Great this works! I was so close 2 hours ago... well I'm going to sleep now :) Thanks again.

Comment: @Reinis - please clarify.  What was the point of append a link that has nothing clickable in the link tag?